# How to use react route params in connected redux selector?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have a component connected to Redux:

```
interface EditProgramCategoryProps {
    category: ProgramCategory;
    fetchAllCategories: () => void;
}

const PureEditProgramCategory: React.FC<EditProgramCategoryProps> = ({
                                                                         category , fetchAllCategories,
                                                                     }) => {
    let { id } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAllCategories();
    }, [fetchAllCategories]);

    return (...);
};

const mapStateToProps => createSelector(
    [ProgramCategorySelectors.getById(id)], <-- this one needs an id
    (category) => ({ category }),
);

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchAllCategories: ProgramCategoryActions.fetchAll.start,
};

export const EditProgramCategory = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PureEditProgramCategory);
```

the `ProgramCategorySelectors.getById` needs an id coming from the routes. What is the correct way to make it available for the selector?
One way that I see is by pushing the id into redux first, however that does not feel correct.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the this.props.location.search to get the querystring value from url

Comment: I don't understand the answer... Besides, it is not in query string...